# Select rows within last complete minute

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find rows in my database which have a timestamp within the last complete minute.

For example:

When it is 12:02:43 --> from 12:01:00 to 12:01:59 (inclusive)
When it is 14:01:00 --> from 14:00:00 to 14:00:59 (inclusive)
When it is 16:24:59 --> from 16:23:00 to 16:23:59 (inclusive)

I found the following statement.

```
select *
from table
where time < to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') 
  and time >= to_date(to_char(sysdate - numtodsinterval(1, 'Minute'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI'), 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI')
```

The statement works, but converting the date to a string and then back to a date seems a little weird. Is there any other method to use only minutes as precision (without seconds)?

Oracle-specific functions could be used, but I'd prefer a standard SQL way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, converting it to string an back seems unnecessary. I'd leave it as a date. How about:

```
SELECT *
  FROM t
 WHERE t BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI') 
             AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI')+1/24/60/60*59;
```

`TRUNC(...,'MI')` chops of the seconds, for instance

```
SELECT trunc(sysdate,'MI'), TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI')+1/24/60/60*59 from dual;
```

returns

```
2018-06-06 11:04:00    2018-06-06 11:04:59
```

EDIT: As David Faber pointed out, this works only if your column has the datatype `DATE`. For the datatype `TIMESTAMP`, you're better of with @MT0's solution.

Comment: If `time` is a TIMESTAMP then precision to the second won't necessarily work as intended. Personally I avoid `BETWEEN` with DATEs and TIMESTAMPs

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MI') -> TRUNC('12:02:43','MI') = 12:02.`
Or you can use this `select extract(MINUTE from current_timestamp) from dual;`

Answer (score 2):

You can truncate timestamps (and dates) to the nearest minute - so you can use `TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI' )` to round to the start of the current minute and subtract `INTERVAL '1' MINUTE` to get the start of the previous minute:

```
select *
from   table_name 
where  time >= TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI' ) - INTERVAL '1' MINUTE
and    time <  TRUNC( SYSTIMESTAMP, 'MI' )
```